# How to wait/finish multiple insert function in for each loop?

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, insert, promise, angular-promise

how to do this asynchronously, print console.log("PRINT THIS, AFTER ALL LOOP IS DONE")

i have forEach inside forEach.

InsertService does not return any value, i just want to insert here.

i don't know how to apply $q and $q.all. pls help.

```
   angular.forEach(MAIN, function (value, key) {

          //#1
         SelectService1.SelectID(value.id).then(function (res) {
             angular.forEach(res, function (value, key) {

              InsertService1.Insert(value).then(function (res) {
                  console.log("NEW INSERTED Service 1!");
                },
                function (err) {
                });

             });
          },
            function (err) {
           });

           //#2
         SelectService2.SelectID(value.id).then(function (res) {
             angular.forEach(res, function (value, key) {

              InsertService2.Insert(value).then(function (res) {
                  console.log("NEW INSERTED Service 2!");
                },
                function (err) {
                });

             });
          },
            function (err) {
           });


           //#3
         SelectService3.SelectID(value.id).then(function (res) {
             angular.forEach(res, function (value, key) {

              InsertService3.Insert(value).then(function (res) {
                  console.log("NEW INSERTED Service 3!");
                },
                function (err) {
                });

             });
          },
            function (err) {
           });
     });
               //
               console.log("PRINT THIS, AFTER ALL LOOP IS DONE");

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

If Insert() returns a promise you can do something like this:

```
var inserts = [];
inserts.push(InsertService1.Insert(value));
inserts.push(InsertService2.Insert(value));
inserts.push(InsertService3.Insert(value));

$q.all(inserts).then(()=>{/*once all have finished*/});
```

Comment: myInsert does not return any value, i just want to insert and after the insert and loop i want to print,"ALL IS DONE"

Comment: @PauloDelaCruz You  cant use .then() if Insert doesn't return a value. Are you sure it doesnt? It looks like its called selectID now and it needs to be returning a promise.

Comment: insertService return a value , but it is always [] or "null" ,..... sir did you understand the flow of my code? could you help me?  i just want to finish all of this loop before going in other functions.

Comment: var select3 = SelectService3.SelectID(value.id);  What would you save select3 variable is equal to?

Comment: the "Main" is list of old position id, now, for each old position id,  SelectService1.SelectID("old position id");  now i will replace it with new positionID (i don't put it there.)  and insert again, i will do this in five table.  now i want to know if all this transaction is done before to proceed in other form.

Comment: SelectService1.SelectID  is "RESPONDENT PEOPLE" now  i want to replace their old position so i insert again.

Comment: So you want each select service to finish before the next one starts?

Answer (score 1):

If each `InsertService.Insert(value)` returns promise,

you can use this

```
var res1 = InsertService1.Insert(value).then( function (res) {
    console.log("NEW INSERTED Service 1!");
}, function (err) {
    console.log("error here");
});

var res2 = InsertService2.Insert(value).then( function (res) {
    console.log("NEW INSERTED service 2 !");
}, function (err) {
    console.log("error here");
});

var res3 = InsertService3.Insert(value).then( function (res) {
    console.log("NEW INSERTED service 3");
}, function (err) {
    console.log("error here");
});

$q.all([res1, res2, re3]).then(function(results){

    console.log(results[0]);   //  this returns promise of res1;
    console.log(results[1]);   //  this returns promise of res2;
    console.log(results[2]);   //  this returns promise of res3; 

    console.log("PRINT THIS, AFTER ALL LOOP IS DONE");
});
```

try this :)

.

.

.

.

EDIT

I'm not sure that what I understood is what you want, here's an example code.

```
function fnOne(param1, param2, ...) {
    return $q(function (resolve, reject) {

       // you can do anything what you want in here
       // and just put success value or error value in resolve or reject

       if(success){
           // result of your code is successful
           resolve(success value);     // this success value will call in $q.all();
       } else {
           // result of your code is failed
           reject(failed value);
       }
    });
}
```

and make `fnTwo`, `fnThree`, ... like above.

Then you can use $q.all like below.

```
$q.all([
    fnOne(
        param1,
        param2,
        ...
    ),
    fnTwo(
        param1,
        param2,
        ...
    ),
    ...
]).then(function (response) {
    // response[0] returns promise of fnOne()
    // response[1] returns promise of fnTwo()
    ....

   console.log("PRINT THIS, AFTER ALL LOOP IS DONE");
});
```

`then` of `$q.all` executes after all functions of `$q.all` arrays are executed.

You can print "PRINT THIS, AFTER ALL LOOP IS DONE" after all functions finished its own work.

Maybe this can help you I think.

Comment: my insertService does not return any value in sqllite, so i just use console just to confirm if it is really saving

Comment: @PauloDelaCruz Can you add code of `InsertService.Insert (value)`? You should check doc about $q. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: this.Insert = function (data) {
            sql.changeDatabase("pmr_data.db");
            return sql.sqlQuery("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO position VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)", UtilityService.getData(data));
        }

Comment: @PauloDelaCruz - You are confused. `InsertService1.Insert(value)` is apparently returning a promise.  If not, then your attempt to use `.then()` with it would have failed before any of your code ran.

Comment: @PauloDelaCruz I updated my answer. please see this.